# Switch case for different users in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, switch-statement

In my automation framework, I have 5 different users with different password. Usernames and passwords are stored in Yaml files, and we call them when necessary. I would like to write common login scenario, so that when I pass a username, the tests should run against that specific role. For example, it can be against Dev Env user, QA Env user, or UAT env user.
I wrote this, but I couldn't figure out, where I am wrong?

...

```
StepHelper.setElement(Login_FIELD).waitUntilVisible().inputToElement(step.getValue(userName.name())); // It will get the specific username and types that on apps login field

  String userName = "User1"; // This should be equal to the return value of above line of code  
  switch (userName) {
case User1:        StepHelper.setElement(PASSWORD_FIELD).waitUntilVisible().inputToElement(step.getValue("P0"));    
        break;
  case User2:        
     StepHelper.setElement(PASSWORD_FIELD).waitUntilVisible().inputToElement(step.getValue("P1"));
        break;
  case User3:
     StepHelper.setElement(PASSWORD_FIELD).waitUntilVisible().inputToElement(step.getValue("P2"));
        break;
  case User4:
     StepHelper.setElement(PASSWORD_FIELD).waitUntilVisible().inputToElement(step.getValue("P3"));
        break;
  case User5:
     StepHelper.setElement(PASSWORD_FIELD).waitUntilVisible().inputToElement(step.getValue("P4"));
        break;
      default:
                System.out.println("No matching username has been found");
            }
```

Comment: This looks like Jave, not C#, so why are you tagging C#?

Comment: Its logic doesn't differ with C# as well

Comment: How does what you wrote misbehave?

Comment: It says user1 cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Well because your `String` has to be inside double quotes. 
So use `case "User1":` and so on.